# cakephp - how to get the data from a model->model->model type relationship

Tags: php, cakephp

I've got three models, **Equipment** which hasmany **Booking**, which in turn hasmany **PaypalTransaction**, and I'm trying to find PaypalTransactions which belong to the booking which belongs to the particular listing I'm dealing with, and which was created less than 1 day ago. All this in the Listings Controller

So in my Listings controller I have

```
$oneDayAgo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 day')); 
$toBeConfdBookings = $this->Equipment->Booking->PaypalTransaction->find('all', array('conditions' => array('PaypalTransaction.created' > $oneDayAgo)));
```

All the models have the appropriate relationships in them as created by cake bake but what ends up in $toBeConfdBookings is all wrong.

Anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What you're saying you want and what you're trying don't relate - where are the conditions for which Equipment and/or Booking you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple answer:**

You cannot run a `find()` on models three-deep like that.  Instead, try just loading the model, then running the `find()`:

```
$this->loadModel('PaypalTransaction');
$oneDayAgo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 day')); 
$toBeConfdBookings = $this->PaypalTransaction->find('all', array('conditions' => array('PaypalTransaction.created' > $oneDayAgo)));
```

(You can only run `find()`s on loaded models or models that are directly related to a loaded model.)

---

**Answer for how I first interpreted your question:**

Normally when you want to pull related results, it's VERY simple - just use [CakePHP's Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).

What you're trying to do, however, is to get the related model data **AND** limit the results based on a related model.  So, because Containable creates separate queries, you cannot limit based on related models - in that case, you'll need to utilize `joins`.

**Code Example:**

```
$oneDayAgo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 day'));
$this->loadModel('Booking'); // if neccessary
$paypalTransactions = $this->Booking->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Booking.equipment_id' => $equipmentId
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'Equipment'
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array('table' => 'paypal_transactions',
            'alias' => 'PaypalTransaction',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'PaypalTransaction.booking_id = Booking.id',
                "PaypalTransaction.created > '".$oneDayAgo."'"
            )
    )
));
```

The above code basically reads:

1. **The find:**  find all Bookings that are owned by `$equipmentId`
2. **The contain:**  also retrieve the data for the associated Equipment (optional)
3. **The join:**  limit the results of the Bookings and Paypal Transactions to only those where the transaction occurred after one day ago (and retrieve the transaction data too)

Comment: Containable is the way to go and I would recommend it as well

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it now you are basically just calling the `PaypalTransaction` model and request its find to return you all transactions in the last day.

`$this->FirstModel->SecondModel->ThirdModel` doesn't mean to connect results from the first model to the second and then to the third, it's only a way to help you load the linked model instead of using `$this->loadModel('ThirdModel')` to load it.

So you still need to place `conditions` according to what you want to do. For example, if it was just one model linked (assuming $this->Booking is set to a record) you could do:

```
$this->Booking->PaypalTransaction->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'PaypalTransaction.created >' => $oneDayAgo,
        'PaypalTransaction.booking_id => $this->Booking->id
    )
);
```

You can't extend this to 2 extra models unless your third model contains keys for both previous models which I doubt it does (and probably shouldn't).

CakePHP will autobind models in find conditions for belongsTo and hasOne associations, and for the rest 2 types you need to be [joining your tables](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables).

It is a little bit of extra work but you get used to it quickly.

Answer (score -1):

When dealing with deeper associations i think you should look at this link. You can retrieve data from tables by bindModel.

http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-bindmodel-to-get-to-deep-relations